# NameError when calling method in CanCan's Ability Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using CanCan for a role-based admin-system in an application I am building. It is sort of a template for webshops, so an admin can have a different role in each webshop he/she has access to. For example: In webshop 1 he is a moderator, and in webshop 2 he is an editor.

So what I need to do in CanCan's ability Class is check what kind of role the current user has in the current shop (current_shop). I wrote this:

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

 def initialize(admin)

   if admin.supervise?(current_shop, controller_gsub)
     can :manage, :all
   elsif admin.manage?(current_shop, controller_gsub)
     can :manage, :all
   elsif admin.access?(current_shop, controller_gsub)
     can :read, :all
   end

 end
end
```

The problem is I can't seem to call the current_shop method from the Ability Class, because I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `current_shop' for #<Ability:0x104df38b0>
```

Does anybody know how to go about this?
Thanx in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can't access any of controller methods into the Ability class. 
What is the business logic? Admin can really manage every single thing if he is a supervisor for a current_shop? or probably he can manage only the things, where he manages the shop?

Then it would be nice to have smth like:

```
class Ability
 include CanCan::Ability

 def initialize(admin)

   can :manage, :all do |obj|
     admin.supervise?(obj.shop) || admin.manage?(obj.shop)
   end
   can :read, :all do |obj|
     admin.access?(obj.shop)
   end

 end
end
```

PS i'm not quite sure the block would work with `:all`, and it's not quite logical to call `.shop` on an unknown class, but that's just to show the way, it's easy enough to list the models for which this will be used

Comment: Thanx for your answer! I've got it working now;) The business logic: An admin can have different roles for each model in the shop, and different roles for each shop. So he/she can be a supervisor of "Order" in shop 1, and only a reader of "Order" in shop 2. :)